Vertices, Edges, and Face selection not showing up
Just started using blender recently and am quite the beginner. For some reason when I go to edit mode, the option for selection the vertices, edges, and faces is not showing up. When I first started out it was there but at some point it disappeared. Not sure how to get it back which is why i'm here? any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit There a tutorial i am trying to follow but this person was able to select the faces, edges, vertices even for curves. How is this possible?

You have created a curve, not a mesh, the options you are talking about don't exist for curves. If you want to convert a curve to mesh, switch to Object mode and right click > Convert To > Mesh.

understood, thank you. Would you mind taking a look at the second image I posted. I've been struggling to understand how the tutorial I was trying to follow was even able to edit a curve

In your second image, the object is not a curve, it's a mesh, maybe it's a curve that has been converted to mesh, to do so, in Object mode right click on your curve > Convert to > Mesh
